# Ingresar codigo alfanúmerico dividido por guión

Tags: javascript, jquery

Como puedo hacer que el usuario ingrese en un input un código así A123-45678945 (Es solo un ejemplo). Es un código de sorteo. El primer valor que sea una letra en mayúscula y los demás sean números. Que sean 12 dígitos. Al digitar los primeros 4 caracteres automáticamente aparezca un guion que los divida de los siguientes 8 caracteres. Estoy empezando a aprender.

Comment: Tu pregunta lleva 3 votos de cierre, deberías leer [ask], editar y mostrar tu avance

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar regular expresions y la funcion test() la cual retorna true si el dato introducido cumple con el formato y si no cumple con el formato retorna false. Ejemplo:

```
// Primero creas el formato que debe tener el dato a introducir
let formato = /^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}?$/;

// Luego compruebas si el dato introducido tiene el formato que definiste arriba con el metodo .test()
let esValido = formato.test('A123-45678945');

// Entonces luego compruebas con una condicion, si retorna true entonces el formato sera corrrecto
if (esValido){
    console.log('Formato Correcto')

}else{ console.log('Formato Incorrecto')  } // si retorna false el formato no es correcto
```

Una breve explicacion de lo que significa:
/^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}?$/

/^    ?$/ Estos marcan el comienzo y el final del string

los que esta dentro de los [] significa que en esa posicion solo se aceptaran esos rangos de caracteres en este caso desde la A hasta la Z, lo que esta dentro de los {} significa la cantidad de caracteres permitdo en esa posicion en este caso solo permite un caracter que este entre A-Z. y asi sucesivamente.
[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{8}

Para agregar el guion puedes usar el evento onChange (usado en la respuesta de
la otra persona) y dentro de la funcion hacer lo siguiente:

```
let valor = objectoInput.value; // Obtienes el valor del input 

// Revisas cuando contenga 4 caracteres
if (valor.length === 4) {  
    let nuevoValor = '${valor}-'; // Luego concatenas el valor con el guion 

    objectoInput.value = nuevoValor; // Y pasas el valor con el guion de nuevo al input 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta amigo. Y si quiero que el guion se pinte en automático después de haber insertado los 4 primeros dígitos, que linea de código debería agregar.

Comment: @ Alexander Casafranca puedes usar el evento onchange (usado en la respuesta de la otra persona)  y en la funcion hacer una condicion como esta:

let valor = objectoInput.value; // Obtienes el valor del input

if (valor.length== 4) { // Revisas cuando contenga 4 caracteres
    let nuevoValor = `${valor}-`; // Luego concatenas el valor con el guion
    objectoInput.value = nuevoValor; // Y pasas el nuevo valor de nuevo al input
}

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo estoy empezando. Crees poder agregar código como parte del comentario para ubicarme mejor. Estoy aprendiendo.

Comment: Estarías aprendiendo si intentases algo por tí mismo en vez de pedir que te hagan las cosas. Inténtalo y si te atascas preguntas, no pidas que te lo hagan.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizano RegExpr con "/^([A-Z]{1}\d{3}-\d{8}?)$/" y delimitando el input con atribbuto html maxlengh=13; sería:

1-Agregar evento onchange al input asi:

```html
<input type="text" onchange="funcionZ(this)" maxlengh="13">
```

2-  la función js:

```js
function funcionZ(objetoinput)
{
  if(objetoinput.value.match(/^([A-Z]{1}\d{3}-\d{8}?)$/)==null)//si no cumple el formato, entonces..
   {
    alert("Formato incorrecto")
    objetoinput.value=""//vacia el input
   }
else{
/....
}
}
```

Op: Si ya usa jquery,sería:

```js
$("#YYYY").change(function(){//YYYY sería id input
   if($(this).val().match(/^([A-Z]{1}\d{3}-\d{8}?)$/)==null)
     {
       alert("Formato incorrecto")
        $(this).val("")
     }
else{
    /....
    }

})
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta amigo. Y si quiero que el guion se pinte en automático después de haber insertado los 4 primeros dígitos, que linea de código debería agregar.